# How do I run code before receiving http request in ktor?

Tags: ktor

First of all, ktor is a awesome product. Is there a way in ktor to be able to run code before a request or a certain set of http requests are processed in the server. I want to be able to check for a certain http header in the request and that the header matches a certain value. If the http header does not exist or the http header value does not match a configured value in the server I want to be able to return a 403 or another http status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [custom plugins API](https://ktor.io/docs/custom-plugins.html):

```
val plugin = createApplicationPlugin("plugin") {
    onCall { call ->
        if (call.request.headers["Custom-Header"] == null) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        install(plugin)

        // ...
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

Or intercept the `ApplicationCallPipeline`:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
    intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Plugins) {
        if (call.request.headers["Custom-Header"] == null) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            finish()
        }
    }

    // ...
}.start(wait = true)
```